# Is Corona SDK suitable for iOS / Android app using tableview navigation

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, titanium, coronasdk

I have an iOS app (developed natively in Objective C) that provides a week-long diet-plan of recipes, plus with shopping lists, and coaching video and audio. The app heavily relies on UITableViews for navigation.

The client has now asked to make this app cross-platform with Android and add some extra content for in-app purchasing.

I've used Corona for a story-book app (also iOS) and I see that tableviews are supported on iOS using Corona Widgets... but I can't find whether they are supported on Android (I don't yet have a device to test on) or whether there is another (reasonable) way to code a UITableView equivalent.

As a bit of background info, I also tried Appcelerator Titanium, but found the loading of tableviews tend to lag as soon as you want to do anything creative with them (like adding images or backgrounds). Also I already have a Corona subscription and don't really want to have to pay for the Titanium+Mods subscription, to support in-App purchasing. ;-D

I would appreciate the insights of those who use Corona for cross-platform of non-game apps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, they sure are supported on Android. My client asked the same and I am about to submit next week. No issues at all on Android :)

Answer (score 1):

yes... Corona is much better sdk for ios..